# PHP - manipulating an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to manipulate an array and i'm a bit stuck on how to proceed and hoping i can be pointed to the right direction

This is the array i currently have:

```
    array(10) { 
["gdlr-room-id"]=> string(4) "3595" 
["gdlr-check-in"]=> string(10) "2016-10-31"
["gdlr-night"]=> string(1) "1" 
["gdlr-check-out"]=> string(10) "2016-11-01" 
["gdlr-room-number"]=> string(1) "1" 
["gdlr-adult-number"]=> string(1) "1" 
["gdlr-children-number"]=> string(1) "1" 
["gdlr-resident"]=> string(8) "resident" 
["service"]=> string(19) "5061,5060" 
["service-amount"]=> string(7) "1,1" }
```

And this is what i want to achieve:

```
 array(10) { 
["gdlr-room-id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "3595" }
["gdlr-check-in"]=> string(10) "2016-10-31"
["gdlr-night"]=> string(1) "1" 
["gdlr-check-out"]=> string(10) "2016-11-01" 
["gdlr-room-number"]=> string(1) "1"
["gdlr-adult-number"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } 
["gdlr-children-number"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
["gdlr-resident"]=> string(8) "resident" 
["service"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "5061" [1]=> string(4) "5060" } 
["service-amount"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" } 
}
```

If i can explain a bit more: if we take the key **gdlr-room-id** as an example: my current array represents a key, value pair as shown `["gdlr-room-id"]=> string(4) "3595"` while my desired result is for the value to be inside another array as shown: `["gdlr-room-id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "3595" }`. This is not for all the key=>value pairs but only a select few as some would remain as they are e.g. `["gdlr-check-in"]=> string(10) "2016-10-31"` is ok as it is

In summary, how do i take some values inside an array(as my current one is) and make some values be inside another array as i have explained above? and while we're at it, any suggestion how i can turn this `["service"]=> string(19) "5061,5060"` into this: `["service"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "5061" [1]=> string(4) "5060" }`? thanks

Comment: You should edit your question and write the arrays in a more reader-friendly way, not as single lines extending into the horizon, forcing the reader to scroll to the right to see everything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of keys for which the value should be expanded into arrays, e.g.

```
$expand_keys = array('gdlr-room-id', 'service');
```

and multiple values are separated by commas, you could do something like

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if (in_array($key, $expand_keys)) {
    $array[$key] = explode(',', $value);
  }
}
```

This will check each key-value pair of your original array and explode its value into an array if the key is in the $expand_keys array.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the elements and explode the values into a new array like this:

```
<?php
$array = array("gdlr-room-id" => "3595",  
          "service" => "5061,5060", 
          "service-amount" => "1,1"
          );

$copied_array = array();

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    $copied_array[$key] = explode(',', $value);
}

print_r($copied_array);
```